# VBA - Print multiple named ranges from one sheet in specified order

Tags: vba, excel, printing, named-ranges

I have some vba that looks like this:

```
Sub Print_Info()

Worksheets("Scorecard (Monthly)").Activate
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "P1,P2,P3,P4,P5"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Preview:=Preview

End Sub
```

P1, P2 etc are all named ranges which are on the same worksheet (Scorecard Monthly).  When running the vba, the resulting print out doesn't output in the correct order ( as specified in the VBA) - I think this is because actually P1 & P2 are below P3, P4 and P5 on the worksheet.  The order of the pages that is printed when using vba is: P4,P1,P2,P5,P3.  The order of the pages in the sheet is P3, P4, P5, P1, P2 - so the print order doesn't really make any sense to me at all when using the VBA.  The reason for needing this is that it is a monthly report, but I have been asked to provide a subset of the information in a slightly different order for a different audience on a regular basis - so it would be handy to just use some VBA to re-order the print out whilst not touching the actual worksheet as it is fine as it is for its usual purpose.

Is there a way I can force excel to print out the range in one file in the correct order from one sheet?  I know I could do something like this:

```
Sub Print_GSCB_Info()

Worksheets("Scorecard (Monthly)").Activate
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "GSCB_P1"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Preview:=Preview
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "GSCB_P2"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Preview:=Preview
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "GSCB_P3"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Preview:=Preview

End Sub
```

However, that would result in separate 'files' being sent to the printer (which isn't ideal as page numbers don't follow etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a little more searching on Google, I found this [post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/macro-print-calling-named-ranges.1063360/), which showed a slightly different method.  Using the following VBA works perfectly, though still not sure why my earlier attempt didn't work!

```
Sub Print_Info_v1()

Worksheets("Scorecard (Monthly)").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("P1,P2,P3,P4,P5").PrintOut

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you if there is a way to directly change the print order. But you could use VBA do this workaround whenever you want to print the monthly report:

1. Create a new sheet
2. Place the ranges (P1-P5) in the right order into this sheet
3. Print the sheet
4. Delete the sheet

Advantage of this solution: You can have two different layouts for the original template and the printed document

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  Will look into doing this, as you say, it's probably one guaranteed way of making it work.